# Sorting by function output in v-for loop in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array that I loop through like this:

```
<template v-for="plan in plans">
   ...
</template>
```

I would like to sort the `plans` array by a calculation based on a few of the `plan`'s properties. Let's call this function `stockReturns(plan)`.

How do I do this?

If I was simple ordering by a property of the plan, I could something like:

```
v-for="plan in plans | orderBy 'attr'"
```

However, I am struggling with the syntax for using a function output in the `orderBy` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom [`computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property which acts like a function to sort the `plans` array:

```
computed: {
  sortedPlans: function(){
    return this.plans.sort(....
  }
}
```

```
<template v-for="plan in sortedPlans">
   ...
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a computed that returns the properly sorted plans.
https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html